# Why didn't I gain reputation when I edited a post?

Tags: support

Why don't I gain reputation when my edit is accepted?

I edited in [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150359/how-to-uninstall-imagemagick/828767#828767) but I didn't gain any reputation.

Comment: Without links to where you were trying to edit, etc. it's impossible to answer this question or provide assistance.  Provide a link and someone like me with ultragodmode can poke and take a look at what actually happened.

Comment: maybe, i edited to add link, or moderator edited this, but i can't see were moderator edited. @EliahKagan i were edited link.

Comment: Another user used the information I posted to get the 'link' to the only edit you posted that was accepted.  They guessed at which link to add.

Comment: @ThomasWard Thomas, I approved an edit and earned an reputation +5.

Comment: Nope, you didn't.  Coincidence.  [Proof #1: your activity page shows the suggested edits were rejected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkRdk.png) [Proof #2: your reputation information page shows the +5 was for an upvote.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWsk5.png)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Given your low reputation (suggesting that maybe you don't know your way around the site much), and some other things which factored in, I took the liberty of looking at your reputation history and contributions.

Of [7 submitted 'suggested edits' at the time of this post](https://askubuntu.com/users/772394/zixuan?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), you had six of them rejected, but only a *single* one ever accepted - [this one](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/789335) which was only 'accepted' because the original poster of the post accepted your edit as valid.

And for the *single* suggested edit you had accepted, you *did* get reputation for it (this is from your reputation tab and is not private knowledge):

[image]

All other 6 submitted edit suggestions were rejected by the community, and you don't get rep for those being rejected.

You *only* gain reputation from an edit if the edit is **accepted** by either the original poster or by community review consensus.  You get absolutely **zero** for rejected edits.

Here's links to all your specific edits, so you can see why they were all rejected.  Had it not been for the OP of the one post, though, you would have 7 rejected edit suggestions instead of 6.  Just keep that in mind...

- [Rejected by the community/reviewers](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/788377)
- [Rejected by the community/reviewers, but ultimately accepted because the original poster approved the edit suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/789335) - this otherwise would have been rejected if Adam had not OK'd your edit suggestion. (This is the one you linked to in your question)
- [Rejected by the community/reviewers](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/789937)
- [Rejected by the community/reviewers](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/790583)
- [Rejected by the community/reviewers](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/790586)
- [Rejected by the community/reviewers](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/790602)
- [Rejected by the community/reviewers](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/790608)

Unless you are the owner of the post which had the edit suggested to it, or you are a diamond moderator such as myself, an "Approve" vote on an edit is worth absolutely nothing unless you get a second "Approve" vote on it.  It requires two "Approve" votes to accept a suggested edit unless you are the owner of the edit-suggested post or a moderator and hit "Approve".

Similarly, it also requires two "Reject" votes to reject a suggested edit, unless you are the original poster of the content that had the edit suggested to it, or a diamond moderator.  (And this is why I don't go through the suggested edit queues much anymore - my moderator diamond gives me binding votes which means whatever I vote is whatever happens to that suggested edit - and in most cases it's 'reject' for reasons similar to why yours were rejected by the ***community*** at-large.)

---

A bit of advice, if I may, also.  Given the edit suggestions you made, **and** the fact that they were *all* rejected for the same reason, you should *really* revisit what you're doing in edits.  Because *all* of your suggested edits fit into the category of "doesn't help readability, or are completely superfluous and unnecessary", or "Actively harm readability", or fit into the category of "You should really propose this as a suggestion to the OP by comments and *not* by adding information to the post via editing".

You should review some of the actually *good* edits done throughout the site, and observe why they are good or not.  Or, ask for guidance on how to edit better (though we'll probably hand you examples of good edits, bad edits, questionable edits, etc. and tell you to review them and burn the differences into your mind before editing things yourself, again.)

Comment: @zixuan no.  No mods rejected.  The *community* via the suggested edit review queue (opens when you have edit privilges at 2k+ reputation for you to review others' suggested edits when they dont' have reputation to just edit without being spot-checked by the community) rejected your edits.  Expand the box at the top of the individual edit review pages to see why yours were rejected.  **ALSO** read the blurb I just added - it's important you see that and read that before you continue to suggest edits.

Comment: @zixuan because **none of your edits were actually accepted**. Unless you are the original poster of a question/answer which had an edit proposed to it, or you are a diamond moderator like myself, an "Approve" vote does nothing, as it requires two approve votes to have a suggested edit accepted.  In most of the cases of your suggested edits, and I gave you links to the data above - it's not secret, you had more "Reject" votes than "Approve" votes. Which is why you got no reputation - your edit was rejected, erased from the queue, and it's equivalent to you not having suggested the edit at all.